# SQL Insert Price with better coincidence of code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an Excel file where I have Products, and in the same file, I have prices that applied for some products based on a column where I have the code of products where applied.

For example, I have a product with code`AAA123`and I have other product with code`AAA124`. And I have 2 prices, one for products that start with`AAA`and another for product`AAA124`.

So, the price for product`AAA`must be the price which applied for products that start with`AAA`and the price for product`AAA124`must be the price for product that applied exactly for products with code `AAA124` because is the better coincidence. If not finds an exactly coincidence, remove one character and make another search, until find best coincidence.

I don't know how to accomplish this. I was thinking in save products in my table products, and for prices create a temporal table, then with a stored procedure find the best coincidence with something like this:

```
SELECT Price, 
   (CASE WHEN code LIKE 'AAA124' THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) +
   (CASE WHEN code LIKE 'AAA12' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) +
   (CASE WHEN code LIKE 'AAA1' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
   (CASE WHEN code LIKE 'AAA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + as rank
FROM Product
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Instead of code hard coded, will be a parameter pass to a stored procedure.

If Anyone could guide me it will be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have control over the database structure?

Comment: LIKE operator without a wildcard doesnt make much sense

Comment: you need a best fit logic, this can be achieved by either editing the schema to hold a new table in it, or by adding your own temporary table. Something like *INNER JOIN (SELECT ID from @T lookupTable where lookupTable.pattern + '%' LIKE code HAVING MAX(pattern.length)) resultingtable.*

this is just a quick throw together and not valid sql. just to get you on the right path

Comment: @RadioSpace what do you mean by control?? ... If I can change the schema?? No, I can't change it, but I can add a new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should find a pretty decent match. You could put it into a scalar function so the price is automatically updated when you import the latest price list into a db table in your server or use it to save the price to the products table if you don't want price changes retroactive.

```
DECLARE @Prices TABLE (CodeMatch VARCHAR(10), Price MONEY )
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ProductCode VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Prices VALUES ('AAA124', 10), ('AAA', 20)
INSERT @Products VALUES ('AAA123'), ('AAA124')
SELECT
    ProductCode,
    ( SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM @Prices ORDER BY LEN(REPLACE(ProductCode, CodeMatch, '')) )
FROM @Products
```

Comment: Buddy, this looks like i was looking for!!... I'm gonna prove in my code but I'm pretty sure that this part of the code (LEN(REPLACE(ProductCode, CodeMatch, '')) it's what i was looking for, thank you so much pal!!