# SQL Insert Price With Better Coincidence for different Codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a variant of this question made for me.

[SQL Insert Price with better coincidence of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445453/sql-insert-price-with-better-coincidence-of-code)

I have this problem, I have a table with items and another with prices. This items could have several prices with different codes, but this price must be the best coincidence in a group of codes.

For example, I have a product with code AAA123 and I have other product with code AAA124. And I have 3 prices, one for products that start with AAA and another 2 for product AAA124. So, i end up with something like this:

```
    DECLARE @Prices TABLE (CodeMatch VARCHAR(10), Price MONEY )
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ProductCode VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Prices VALUES ('AAA124', 10), ('AAA', 20), ('AAA124', 15)
INSERT @Products VALUES ('AAA123'), ('AAA124')
SELECT
    ProductCode,
    ( SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM @Prices ORDER BY LEN(REPLACE(ProductCode, CodeMatch, '')) )
FROM @Products
```

How can i get that 2 prices that can applied with code AAA124 can be selected? With the example above, only get the first AAA124, but instead i need that both prices can be added to my select.

I've tried with distinct and group by but I can't get this works.

Thank you for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22596)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Prices TABLE (CodeMatch VARCHAR(10), Price MONEY )
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ProductCode VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Prices VALUES ('AAA124', 10), ('AAA', 20), ('AAA124', 15), ('AAA12',30)
INSERT @Products VALUES ('AAA123'), ('AAA124'), ('AAA')


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT p.ProductCode, 
          pr.Price, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY P.ProductCode ORDER BY LEN(pr.CodeMatch) DESC) RN
    FROM @Products p
    INNER JOIN @Prices pr
        ON p.ProductCode LIKE pr.CodeMatch + '%'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Prices pr2 WHERE pr2.CodeMatch = p.ProductCode)
)
SELECT p.ProductCode, pr.Price
FROM @Products p
INNER JOIN @Prices pr
    ON p.ProductCode = pr.CodeMatch
UNION
SELECT p.ProductCode, p.Price
FROM CTE P
WHERE P.RN = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22596/0)**:

```
| PRODUCTCODE | PRICE |
|-------------|-------|
|         AAA |    20 |
|      AAA123 |    30 |
|      AAA124 |    10 |
|      AAA124 |    15 |
```

Comment: I can't use Like because if I have a price that applies for products that start AAA and other for product AAA123 it will take both prices and what I want is the best coincidence.

Comment: @user3243074 This does what you want I am updating answer to show results

Comment: Yes @Steve Ford, that's how I ended solving my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @user3243074 if this solved your problem, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry buddy... I had forgot, I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your logic, the issue is the `1` in the `TOP 1`.  What you want is everything with the same length as the best one.  This suggests `DENSE_RANK()`.

Now, because you are returning (potentially) more than one price for a product, you cannot use a correlated subquery.  Instead, use `APPLY`.  So, I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT p.ProductCode, pr.Price
FROM @Products p CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT Price,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEN(REPLACE(ProductCode, CodeMatch, ''))) as seqnum
      FROM @Prices pr
     ) pr
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed3fb/1) is a SQL Fiddle.  It seems to do what you want.

Comment: I prove with this example buddy but instead is returning me all the  prices for all the products.